# Angular Route version

Tags: angularjs

Soy nuevo en esto. estoy usando la version 1.6.4 de AngularJS (Angular 1) y estoy siguiendo un tutorial para implementar la navegación por rutas `<script src="bower_components/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>` pero al parecer con esta versión no funciona. He probado con una versión inferior (por ejemplo la 1.5.0 y si funciona. Hay alguna alternativa?

Answer (score 1):

Buenas,

Tal vez esto te ayude y tenga que ver con tu problema.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working

De igual manera te dejo la documentación oficial, es posible que haya cambiado algo entre las versiones y estes usando algo que ya no esta activo para angular 1.6.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Espero haber podido ayudar en algo.

Saludos.